# Chrome extension - unable to catch javascript error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to catch all JavaScript errors from [a specific website](http://demo.kombo.com/?server_id=108&player_uuid=a) via a chrome extension. I am very inexperienced with javascript and for some odd reason my error handler isnt catching all of the errors, most importantly, the one on line 191 "Load timeout for modules":
https://hastebin.com/atuwiboqec.js

The error "script error" on line 507 comes through just fine.

This is my content.js file that I have under "content_scripts" in the manifest, it runs at document_start:

```
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.src=chrome.runtime.getURL("myscript.js");
script.async=false;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

This is my myscript.js file:

```
window.addEventListener("error", handleException, false);
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", handleException, false);

function handleException(I_sMsg) {

    console.log("Error0 occured: " + I_sMsg.message);

    return cancelEvent(I_sMsg);
};

window.onerror = function ErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
  console.log("Error1 occured: " + errorMsg);
  return false;
};

window.addEventListener("timeout", function(e) {
  console.log("Error2 occured: " + e.error.message);
  return false;
});
```

When the error "script error" occurs, both Error0 and Error1 messages get printed. When the error "load timeout for modules" occurs, nothing happens even though the error shows up as "Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules" in the chrome console, in red, with log level "error". This indicates that the error is being thrown:

[error in console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdhfV.jpg)

How can I catch that error, or even better, all errors from that site?

P.S I am unsure of how to trigger that load timeout error. It only happens every now and then. I believe a slow network is the cause.

EDIT: Updated the url domain to a backup one as it wasnt resolving.

Comment: Sounds like Chrome prints it directly to the console.

Comment: @wOxxOm When using chromes remote debugging, it isn't showing in the console messages or in the log messages either. However, when using selenium chrome driver, it does show. Any ideas?

Comment: Googling the error message indicates it's from require.js and in [chromium source](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=%22Load+timeout%22+case:yes) it's only inside tests which aren't shipped with the browser.